# Apache Ignite CacheRebalanceMode Is Not Respected By Nodes

Tags: java, c#, ignite

*The setup:* Hello folks I have a simple Apache Ignite setup with two Ignite instances configured as server nodes over C# and one Ignite instance as a client node over java.

*What is the goal:* Populate data on instance 1 and instance 2 but avoid movement of data between them. In other words data receiced on each node must stay in node. Then using the java client to run queries against the two nodes either combined (distributed join) or per node (using affinity).

*The issue:* With one server node everything works as expected, however on more than one server nodes, data of the cluster is balancing  between the x member nodes even if I have expliccitly set the `CacheRebalanceMode` to `None` which should disable the rebalance between then nodes. The insert time is increase by 4x-10x times, function to each node's populated data.

P.S. I have tried change the cache mode from `Partitioned` to `Local` where each node will have isolated the data in it's internal H2 db however in that case the Java client is unable to detect the nodes or read any data from the cache of each node.

Java Client Node

```java
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        // Enable client mode.
        cfg.setClientMode(true);

        // Setting up an IP Finder to ensure the client can locate the servers.
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));

        // Configure Ignite to connect with .NET nodes
        cfg.setBinaryConfiguration(new BinaryConfiguration()
                        .setNameMapper(new BinaryBasicNameMapper(true))
                        .setCompactFooter(true)

        // Start Ignite in client mode.
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

        
        IgniteCache<AffinityKey, Trade> cache0 = ignite.cache(CACHE_NAME);
        IgniteCache<AffinityKey, BinaryObject> cache = cache0.withKeepBinary();
    
        // execute some queries to nodes
```

C# Server Node

```cs
               IIgnite _ignite = Ignition.Start(IgniteUtils.DefaultIgniteConfig()));

                // Create new cache and configure queries for Trade binary types.
                // Note that there are no such classes defined.
                var cache0 = _ignite.GetOrCreateCache<AffinityKey, Trade>("DEALIO");

                // Switch to binary mode to work with data in serialized form.
                _cache = cache0.WithKeepBinary<AffinityKey, IBinaryObject>();

               //populate some data ...

        public static IgniteConfiguration DefaultIgniteConfig()
        {
            return new IgniteConfiguration
            {

               
                PeerAssemblyLoadingMode = PeerAssemblyLoadingMode.CurrentAppDomain,
                BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration
                {
                    NameMapper = new BinaryBasicNameMapper { IsSimpleName = true },
                    CompactFooter = true,
                    TypeConfigurations = new[] {
                        new BinaryTypeConfiguration(typeof(Trade)) {
                            Serializer = new IgniteTradeSerializer()
                        }
                    }
                },
                DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
                {
                    IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder
                    {
                        Endpoints = new[] { "127.0.0.1:47500..47509" }
                    },
                    SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.10)
                },
                Logger = new IgniteNLogLogger(),
                CacheConfiguration = new[]{
                    new CacheConfiguration{
                            PartitionLossPolicy=PartitionLossPolicy.Ignore,
                            RebalanceMode=CacheRebalanceMode.None,
                            Name = CACHE_NAME,
                            CacheMode = CacheMode.Partitioned,
                            Backups = 0,
                            QueryEntities = new[] { 
                                new QueryEntity(typeof(AffinityKey), typeof(Trade))
                            }
                }
            }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`CacheRebalanceMode.None` basically means "do not move data to a newly added node", not "keep all entries locally". `cache.Put` will still send the data to a primary node for a given key.

The following code demonstrates how `None` mode works:

```cs
var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
{
    AutoGenerateIgniteInstanceName = true,
    CacheConfiguration = new[]
    {
        new CacheConfiguration
        {
            Name = "c",
            RebalanceMode = CacheRebalanceMode.None
        }
    }
};

var ignite1 = Ignition.Start(cfg);
var cache1 = ignite1.GetCache<int, int>("c");

// Put before starting the second node.
cache1.PutAll(Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x, x)));

var ignite2 = Ignition.Start(cfg);
var cache2 = ignite2.GetCache<int, int>("c");

Thread.Sleep(5000); // Wait for the rebalance.
Console.WriteLine(cache1.GetLocalSize());
Console.WriteLine(cache2.GetLocalSize()); // 0 with None
```

With `None` mode you'll see zero size of the second cache, and with any other mode it won't be zero.

Comment: That is correct but still doesn't answer my question. How can I force the data to stay in the node where have been populated in the first place and still be querable by the Ignite Client node?  So in your example if you start another ignite instance in client mode you will not be able to ask queries on the data resit in the local nodes.

Comment: @Chris you can query the data from any node, Ignite will take care of routing the request correctly.

Comment: As discussed on Ignite summit, I now understand the problem better - rebalance does not make sense to you because data becomes stale and useless very quickly. However, I don't have anything better than the code snippet above. It should work reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

> Populate data on instance 1 and instance 2 but avoid movement of data between them. In other words data receiced on each node must stay in node.

The problem is, that's not how Ignite works. A cache is really a cluster-wide concept; that is, you put data into the cache, not into a specific node. If you want to keep data on a specific node, you can use the LOCAL cache but you've already seen the downside to that.

Rather than force data onto a specific machine, Ignite uses the concept of "[affinity](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation)." You tell it how data is related and it will *automatically* keep those data together.

Putting data into a specific machine works fine until you want to change the number of nodes (or have one fail). By defining affinity, Ignite can scale up and down automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but either with affinity feature does not solve the problem. What affinity will do is to keep data correlated between them on the same node e.g. a table User who has a relation on table UserRole the relation between them will be hosted on the same node. However does not guarantee that data generated from Node A will stay on Node A. My current application setup needs real time updates < 300ms so imagine if Ignite has to router half of the updates on other nodes.

Comment: Forcing data to a specific node is generally an anti-pattern. But it can be done with cluster groups or a local cache and compute tasks to execute queries.

Comment: Do you have an example code for the use case you just described?!